# R create new list of dataframes of a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes (list named result) and now I want to create a new list of dataframes but somehow I cannot figure this out.
I tried two versions, one with a loop and one with lapply. In this particular case I want to extract some columns (with a specific name) and store it in a new list of dataframes (called l)

```
l<- lapply (results, function (i)results[[i]][, c("c1","c2")])

for (c in seq_along(results)){
  print(l[i]<-results[[i]][, c("c1","c2")])
}
```

The first function tells me that it is invalid for type list to do this.
The second function only prints it but this doesnt allow further analyses. If I do not use print, only the last option gets evaluated.
Ideally, I want to do several things with the "l" dataframes in this loop, e.g., melting l and adding columns.
Do you have any hints what I have been misunderstanding?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Try `l1 <- lapply(results, function(x) x[c('c1', 'c2')])`

Comment: This seems to be easy, I should have figured that out myself--- thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably should be:

```
l<- lapply (results, function (df) df[  c("c1","c2") ])
```

If you wanted to index with the sequence number, it could also be

```
l<- lapply ( seq_along(results) , function (i)results[[i]][, c("c1","c2")])
```